# Shiny only calculating when the user is looking at the output

Tags: r, shiny

I'm having a problem with Shiny and I don't know if it's a bug or I'm missing something. I tried to find a solution but I can't seem to find references to this problem online.

I have a function that is supposed to run when I press a button, but it's only running when the user is looking at the output after the button is pressed.

It's somewhat weird, so I created a minimal example. I have two tabs. In the first, I choose a number (mean), and in the second tab I plot values around that mean. The button is in the first tab, but the "create.plot" function only starts to run when you go to tab2. To make things clear, I created this 'loading.div', which shows up when the function is running.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

create.plot <- function(mean)
{
  shinyjs::show('loading.div')
  y <- rep(NA,10)
  for(i in 1:10)
  {
    y[i] <- rnorm(1,mean=mean)
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
  }
  shinyjs::hide('loading.div')

  return(list(y=y, test='Now it runs from tab1'))
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  run.function <- eventReactive(input$run,create.plot(input$mean))

  output$plot.y <- renderPlot({
    plot(run.function()[['y']])
  })

  output$test <- renderText({
    run.function()[['test']]
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  hidden(div(id='loading.div',h3('Loading..'))),
  tabsetPanel(

  tabPanel('tab1',
    numericInput(inputId = 'mean',label='Mean', value=1),
    actionButton(inputId = 'run', label='Run')
    #,textOutput('test')   ## Uncommenting this line, it works.
    ),

  tabPanel('tab2',
    plotOutput('plot.y'))
  )
)

shinyApp(server=server,ui=ui)
```

To make sure that the problem was that the user was not looking at the output when at tab1, I created a test string. If you uncomment that line, the problem is "fixed": the function runs directly after the user hits the button. However, that only works because he is looking at an output in tab1.

This is becoming a serious problem because I have a shiny dashboard with many tabs. There are tabs with inputs and tabs with outputs. I'd like the function to run when I click a button, but it's only running when the user goes to the "outputs" tab.

Is this a known problem? Are there workarounds?

Comment: That is the way it is supposed to work. That is what being "reactive" is all about. If you want to force something to be calculated, put it in a `reactiveValue` and calculate it with `observeEvent`, and then display the values with `reactive` blocks.

Comment: Watch part one and part two of these videos to understand it correctly. https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/shiny-developer-conference/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R Shiny Tabsets simultaneous processing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757876/r-shiny-tabsets-simultaneous-processing)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Reactive elements that are not visible are considered "suspended" and will not update their values until they are unsuspended.  Be default, this doesn't happen until they are rendered on the screen.

You can set an element to update even when not visible by changing its suspended status.  You do this with the `outputOptions` function.

for the `output$test` element, you would need to run

```
outputOptions(output, "test", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
```

If you have multiple elements you want to update even when not visible, you can use

```
lapply(c("test1", "test2", "test3"),
       function(x) outputOptions(output, x, suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
```

Be aware, however, that this means that all of the calculations will be performed at once.  Depending on the size of your calculations, this could slow down the app performance.  For instance, if there is a plot that is generated and takes some time to render, and only a small portion of users will ever look at the plot, it might be prudent to leave it suspended until a user requests it to prevent slowing down the calculation of more commonly used elements.

### EDITS

It turns out "plots cannot render in advance because they have no width and height. " (https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1409).  So we have to do some trickery to make the plot render in advance:

We can choose the dimensions of our plot instead of letting `shiny` fit it automatically.  This will mean that the plot will not grow if the screen is enlarged.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

create.plot <- function(mean)
{
  print("working.....")
  shinyjs::show('loading.div')
  y <- rep(NA,10)
  for(i in 1:10)
  {
    y[i] <- rnorm(1,mean=mean)
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
  }
  shinyjs::hide('loading.div')

  y
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  run.function <- eventReactive(input$run,create.plot(input$mean))

  output$plot.y <- renderPlot({
      plot(run.function())
    },
    width = 72 * 5,
    height = 72 * 3
  )

  outputOptions(output, "plot.y", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
}

ui <- fluidPage(shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
                hidden(div(id='loading.div',h3('Loading..'))),
                tabsetPanel(

                  tabPanel('tab1',
                           numericInput(inputId = 'mean',label='Mean', value=1),
                           actionButton(inputId = 'run', label='Run')
                  ),

                  tabPanel('tab2',
                           plotOutput('plot.y'))
                )
)

shinyApp(server=server,ui=ui)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think this is only partially solving my problem. If I add the line outputOptions(output, "plot.y", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE) (note that, in my case, plot.y is the hidden object, not test), I'm able to run the function from tab1 only if I have already visualized tab2. However, if I open the app and click run without changing tabs first, it does not work. I assume it has to do with the way shiny initializes its tabs

Comment: At first I thought it might have something to do with `eventReactive`, but further investigation brought me to https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1409 which shows that `plotOutput` is choosing not to run when there is no output to plot because it can't determine the size.  If we set the plot size explicitly, the `outputOptions` will work.  I will include two examples of how to make this work with a plot in my answer, but truthfully, Mike's answer is probably the easiest approach to reason with.

Comment: well, could only get one example working, so I'm going to let this go at this point.  Like I said, given the constraints of `plotOutput`, I think Mike's answer is your best approach.

Answer (score 5):

Actuall that is the way it is supposed to work. That is what being "reactive" is all about - it does lazy evaluation with caching (so you do not have to). If you want to force something to be calculated, put it in a `reactiveValue` and calculate it with `observeEvent` (this does eager execution), and then display the values with `reactive` blocks.

I modified your example to do that here:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

create.plot <- function(mean) {
  shinyjs::show('loading.div')
  y <- rep(NA,10)
  for (i in 1:10) {
    y[i] <- rnorm(1,mean = mean)
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
  }
  shinyjs::hide('loading.div')

  return(list(y = y,test = 'Now it runs from tab1'))
}

server <- function(input,output,session) {

  rv <- reactiveValues(plotvals=NULL)

  observeEvent(input$run,{rv$plotvals <- create.plot(input$mean) })

  output$plot.y <- renderPlot({
    req(input$run)
    plot(rv$plotvals[['y']])
  })

  output$test <- renderText({
    rv$plotvals[['test']]
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  hidden(div(id = 'loading.div',h3('Loading..'))),
  tabsetPanel(

  tabPanel('tab1',
    numericInput(inputId = 'mean',label = 'Mean',value = 1),
    actionButton(inputId = 'run',label = 'Run')
#,textOutput('test')   ## Uncommenting this line, it works.
    ),

  tabPanel('tab2',
    plotOutput('plot.y'))
  )
)

shinyApp(server = server,ui = ui)
```

Yielding this (right after pressing the run button):

[image]

And then when that text goes away, you can see the plot in tab2 immediately.

[image]

To better understand this stuff, and the lazy nature of reactives and the eager nature of `observe`, see Joe Cheng's presentation on it here. It is well worth the time:

https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/shiny-developer-conference/

In fact the reactive nature of Shiny is exactly what makes it so productive, once you get used to it - it is rather different.